# Confusing tf transforms

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working a lot with transform matrices these days and the tf nomenclature doesn't make things easier.
For tf_echo, the input frames are defined as such:

```
tf_echo <source_frame> <target_frame>
```

When using Python and looking up for a transform it is as follows:

```
 lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, time) -> position, quaternion
```

But what I get are two inverse transforms even though I use the same source_frame and target_frame. Why is that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229463/confusing-tf-transforms/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Agreed. This was quite confusing to me also. This has been asked before, but it was hard for me to find the previous question and your question's title is much more likely to be found in future searches methinks.

http://answers.ros.org/question/194046/the-problem-of-transformerlookuptransform/

to Quote tully,

> The lookup API is named with respect
> to transforming data from the source
> frame into the target frame.
>
> When referring to transform between
> coordinate frames (transforming the
> frames, it is the inverse of the
> transform of data between the two
> frames)
>
> Depending on the documentation if
> you're referring to the transform
> value for the data, or the transform
> value of the coordinate frames you get
> the inverse value.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2016-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-03-18**:
Ah, I see what he is saying. Transform can be a verb and a noun - you transform the data using a transform, err confusing. Oh well, it's not a big problem, we just gotta be careful and make sure to test in simulation first!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what is missing here is a concrete math proof.

I came across this on the coursera website, see [this link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-flight/lecture/dpE88/transformations). **Watch from 10:40  till the end**.

Read this **after** watching the above video once -

The video explains how to get source datapoint using the Rotation Matrix. The **opposite** ( by taking a simple transpose of Rotation matrix ) is true for
getting the **target data point in the source frame**, you have to use the **inverse** of the Rotation matrix ( Rotation required to convert **source to target** basis vectors )

Hence it also explains ( taken from the above answer by @tbh )

> "When referring to transform between
> coordinate frames (transforming the
> frames, it is the inverse of the
> transform of data between the two
> frames)"

---

Originally posted by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) with karma: 121 on 2018-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1